# How do I correctly update state_timeout in gen_statem?

Tags: erlang, timeout, state-machine

I need to write a module that implements gen_statem behaviour. I need to simulate ATM work and one of the features is to give the card back if the person doesn't push any button for 10 secs.
I have to states:

**waiting_for_card** - the only event that is possible is inserting a card; when the card is inserted I change the state to *waiting_for_pin* with state_timeout = 10000ms after which the state should be automatically changed to *waiting_for_card*.

**waiting_for_pin** - if the *number*-button is pressed I should put the number to an input list and restart the timer, while the *enter* and *cancel* buttons have different state transitions that should just cancel the timer

Here is the code snippet:

```erlang
waiting_for_card({call, From}, {insert, Card}, #state{accounts = Accounts}) ->
  case check_if_user_is_in_list(Card, Accounts) of
    true ->
      NewState = #state{
        accounts = Accounts,
        insertedCard = Card
      },
      {next_state, waiting_for_pin, NewState, [{reply, From, ok}, {state_timeout, 10000, timeout}]};
    false ->
      {keep_state_and_data, [{reply, From, {error, "ATM doesn't servise this card"}}]}
  end;

waiting_for_pin({call, From}, {button, cancel}, #state{accounts = Accounts}) ->
  NewState = #state{accounts = Accounts},
  {next_state, waiting_for_card, NewState, [{reply, From, {ok, "Card returned"}}, {state_timeout, cancel}]};

waiting_for_pin({call, From}, {button, enter}, #state{accounts = Accounts, input = Input, insertedCard = Card}) ->
  case check_pin(Card, lists:reverse(Input), Accounts) of
    true ->
      NewState = #state{
        accounts = Accounts,
        insertedCard = Card
      },
      {next_state, waiting_for_sum, NewState, [{reply, From, {ok, "Valid pin, enter the sum to withdraw"}}, {state_timeout, cancel}]};
    false ->
      NewState = #state{
        accounts = Accounts
      },
      {next_state, waiting_for_card, NewState, [{reply, From, {error, "Wrong pin, get your card"}}, {state_timeout, cancel}]}
  end;

waiting_for_pin(cast, {button, Button}, #state{accounts = Accounts, input = Input, insertedCard = Card}) ->
  NewState = #state{accounts = Accounts, input = [Button + 48 | Input], insertedCard = Card},
  {keep_state, NewState, [{state_timeout, cancel}, {state_timeout, 10000, timeout}]};
```

As you can see, now I just cancelling and start a new timeout in *Action* argument of returned value of state function.

Pattern {state_timeout, update, EventContent} doesn't restart the timer is I have tested.

Am I right or I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to simulate ATM work and one of the features is to give the
>   card back if the person doesn't push any button for 10 secs.
>   ...
>   As you can see, now I just cancelling and start a new timeout in
>   Action argument of returned value of state function.

According to the gen_statem docs for a [state_timeout](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html#type-state_timeout):

> Setting this timer while it is running will restart it with the new
>   time-out value.

[And](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html#type-enter_action),

> enter_action() =
>       hibernate |
>       {hibernate, Hibernate :: hibernate()} |
>       timeout_action() |
>       reply_action()
>
> These transition actions can be invoked by returning them from the
>   state callback ...
>
> ...
>
> Actions that set transition options override any previous of the same
>   type... For example, the last event_timeout() overrides any previous
>   event_timeout() in the list.

As for this:

> Pattern {state_timeout, update, EventContent} doesn't restart the
>   timer is I have tested.

According to the [timeout_update_action()](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html#type-timeout_update_action) docs:

> Updates a time-out with a new EventContent.  See timeout_action() for
>   how to start a time-out.

So, `update` only updates the EventContent for the timeout--not the time for the timeout.

Here's an example of what you can do:

```
-module(card).
-behaviour(gen_statem).
-compile(export_all).

%client functions:
start_transaction() ->
    gen_statem:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, no_args, []).

end_transaction() ->
    gen_statem:stop(?MODULE).

insert_card() ->
    gen_statem:call(?MODULE, card_inserted).

button(Number) ->
    gen_statem:call(?MODULE, {button, Number}).

% required callback functions
callback_mode() ->
    state_functions.

init(no_args) ->
    {ok, waiting_for_card, no_data}.

terminate(_Reason, _PreviousState, _Data) ->
    io:format("terminating..."),
    ok.


% waiting_for_card state:
waiting_for_card({call, From}, card_inserted, _Data) ->
    io:format("state waiting_for_card: call.~n"),
    {
        next_state, waiting_for_pin, _Pin=[], 
        [{reply, From, card_detected}, {state_timeout, 10000, return_card}] 
    }.

% waiting_for_pin state: 
waiting_for_pin(state_timeout, return_card, _Pin) ->
    io:format("state waiting_for_pin: state_timeout.~n"),
    io:format("Sorry, you took too long to enter your pin.~n"),
    io:format("Here is your card back.~n"), 
    {next_state, waiting_for_card, reset_pin};

waiting_for_pin({call, From}, {button, Button}, Pin) ->
    io:format("state waiting_for_pin: call.~n"),
    io:format("You pressed button: ~w.~n", [Button]),
    NewPin = [Button|Pin], %whatever
    {
        keep_state,
        NewPin,
        [{state_timeout, 10000, return_card}, {reply, From, got_number}]
    }.
```

Here's a test run in the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs/gen_statem$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(card).                 
card.erl:3: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,card}

2> card:start_transaction().
{ok,<0.71.0>}

3> card:insert_card().      
state waiting_for_card: call.
card_detected
state waiting_for_pin: state_timeout.
Sorry, you took too long to enter your pin.
Here is your card back.

4> card:insert_card().
state waiting_for_card: call.
card_detected

5> card:button(4).          
state waiting_for_pin: call.
You pressed button: 4.
got_number
state waiting_for_pin: state_timeout.
Sorry, you took too long to enter your pin.
Here is your card back.

6> card:insert_card().
state waiting_for_card: call.
card_detected

7> card:button(4).    
state waiting_for_pin: call.
You pressed button: 4.
got_number

8> card:button(5).    
state waiting_for_pin: call.
You pressed button: 5.
got_number
state waiting_for_pin: state_timeout.
Sorry, you took too long to enter your pin.
Here is your card back.

9> ...waits here for 1 minute plus...
```

Comment: Thank, i got it!